# Python How to Query API from Luno.com with HTTP Authentication

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am writing a python script which calls the API of Luno.com. It will form part of a larger python script(testing the new API call in a separate script) in which I have already made successful calls to a different site's API, however it did not require authentication. Luno documentation says it needs an API key (which I have) and to use the id and key secret as the username and password in a normal HTTP authentication, being new to python I googled how to do basic HTTP authentication and found this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
result = requests.get('url', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I tried using this, but can not seem to get it right no matter what I try,I get the following error when printing the response code and the json output:

```
<Response [404]>
{'error': 'Cannot find that market', 'error_code': 'ErrMarketNotFound', 'error_action': {}}
```

I will include my python script and also links to the luno API sections which are applicable. The URL I want to access is https://api.luno.com/api/1/ticker , used to get the currency pair.

https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api

https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#operation/getTicker

Screenshots if you don't want to click the links:
[image]
[image]

Python Code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

urlLuno = 'https://api.luno.com/api/1/ticker'

statsAuthLuno = requests.get(urlLuno, auth=('idhere', 'secretkeyhere'))

print(statsAuthLuno)
print(statsAuthLuno.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

the `ticker` API does not require authentication but it does require the market pair [as seen here](https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#operation/GetTicker)

```py
requests.get(urlLuno, params={"pair": "XBTMYR"})
```

should get you the details you need.

Or you can [get all tickers](https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#operation/ListTickers)